# Create different seeds for different instances of "Random"

Tags: c#, .net, random

People usually ask why they get always the same numbers when they use `Random`. In their case, they unintenionally create a new instance of `Random` each time (instead of using only one instance), which of course leads to the same numbers the whole time. But in my case, **I do need** several instances of `Random` which return different number streams.

Using hard-coded seeds is a bad idea in my opinion since you get the same values again and again after restarting the program. What about this:

```
int seed1 = (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks - 13489565;
int seed2 = (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks - 5564;
```

I know this looks silly and naive, but it would avoid the same values after every restart and both of the seeds should differ. Or maybe

```
Random helper = new Random();
int seed1 = helper.Next(1, int.MaxValue);
int seed2 = helper.Next(1, int.MaxValue);
```

As you can see, I am a bit uncreative here and need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Any need to _be_ creative? I can't see any issue with either of your approaches.

Comment: Your thought of using a random to create the seeds for your different random number generators seems fine to me.  Its what I was going to suggest until I finished reading the post.

Comment: Now that I think of it, there _could_ be an issue with the second approach if the PRNG is not very smart

Comment: And I still can't think of why you would need two different random generators instead of just one that feeds two streams ...

Comment: No, sorry for being unprecise. I Just don't know how to generate "strong seeds". My application does not need to be super precise in terms of random numbers, but I think my solutions are too simple.

Comment: @ceran any pair of seeds should be equally distinct (uncorrelated).

Comment: @WiktorZychla perhaps for multithreading.  It would be easier to give each thread its own Random instance rather than synchronizing a single one, and it would avoid lock contention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jon Skeet, suggests using a secondary `Random` object and a lock to create a `Random` object factory. For example:

```
    public static Random NewRandom() 
    { 
        lock (globalLock) 
        { 
            return new Random(secondaryRandom.Next()); 
        } 
    }
```

[Take a look at the complete source code in Jon Skeet's blog.](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I would use your second approach:

```
int randomCount = 10;
Random seeder = new Random();
var randoms = Enumerable.Range(0, randomCount)
    .Select(i => new Random(seeder.Next()))
    .ToList();
```

This uses linq to create a list of 10 differently-seeded Random instances.  You'll therefore need `using System.Linq;` to have access to the `Select` extension method.

You could also reuse the seeder as one of your instances:

```
int randomCount = 10;
Random seeder = new Random();
var randoms = Enumerable.Range(0, randomCount - 1)
    .Select(i => new Random(seeder.Next()))
    .Concat(new [] { seeder })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cryptographic generator to create your seeds e.g.

```
public static Random CreateRandom()
{
    using (var rng = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        rng.GetNonZeroBytes(bytes);
        int seed = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
        return new Random(seed);
    }
}
```

Of course, if you just need ints then you could use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` to generate them directly, although `System.Random` is probably faster.